# FbDataReader issues with Unique constraint

Tags: c#, datatable, firebird, unique-constraint, firebird2.5

I am loading a `FbDataReader` into a DataTable for a table that contains a unique constraint of the following type (full table DDL)

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
    PK_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    STRING_KEY CHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE NONE,
    INT_KEY INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT PK_MY_TABLE PRIMARY KEY (PK_ID));  

ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MY_TABLE_INT_KEY FOREIGN KEY (INT_KEY) REFERENCES MY_OTHER_TABLE (INT_KEY) 
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT U_MY_TABLE UNIQUE (STRING_KEY, INT_KEY);
```

What I want is to be able to have several entries for the same `STRING_KEY` provided they have different `INT_KEY`. Note that I can have `INT_KEY` as `NULL` records, but if so, the `(STRING_KEY, NULL)` record should also be unique.

Moreover, I have a foreign key on `INT_KEY`.

Now, when I load my `FbDataReader` as follows:

```
FbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Load(reader);
```

I get an error:

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

So here I go testing: 
1. removing the above unique constraint then the load works
2. using a unique constraint with only the `STRING_KEY` works, i.e. I definitely don't have violating records: the single key being unique, the combined key must also be unique - or I misunderstood the meaning of Unique constraints.
3. Setting all `NULL` values in the `INT_KEY` doesn't change anything - same error occurs when loading the data table.

Of course, I could load the data into a `DataSource` and set `EnforceConstraints` to false, which works. But I feel not comfortable by having an error I don't understand and fixing it with ignoring it...

Comment: Could you post the entire definition of the table?